# reformat date to YYYY/MM/DD and replace column data in CSV

Tags: python, python-2.7

I'm a newbie python programmer and I have a CSV that is simple, looks like this:

```
FROM_ID,JOIN_DATE,FAV_SPORT
100004,06/08/2016,Football
100006,06/08/2016,Tennis
100007,06/08/2016,Football
100009,06/08/2016,Basketball
```

I am trying to rewrite the date to YYYY/MM/DD. So far I have gotten this far:

```
import csv
f = open('reg.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    parts = row[1].split('/')
print parts[2]
```

All this does is print out the year (YYYY), which is one step closer :) Can anyone advise how to reformat the parts into the YYYY/MM/DD format?

Also, I notice python doesnt have case/select. How would I create a find/replace on "FROM_ID" and replace them with another number? Like:

*if FROM_ID is equal to X then Y*

Thanks in advance for any help. I have scoured the internet for hours and I am a touch stuck but hoping I can get moving along. Thanks!

Comment: You want to replace one `FROM_ID` with another one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reccommend using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv("path_to_your_file")

def change_date_format(date):

    # create a list of the substrings separated by '/',
    # so in your case ['DD', 'MM', 'YYYY'] 
    split_dt = date.split("/")

    return split_dt[2] + '/' + split_dt[1] + '/' + split_dt[0]   

#apply this function to all elements of 'JOIN_DATE' columns
df.loc[:, 'JOIN_DATE'] = df.loc[:, 'JOIN_DATE'].apply(change_date_format)
```

On your second question, you can do:

```
to_replace = ['X', 'Z']
replace_values = ['Y', 'W']
replace_dict = dict(zip(to_replace, replace_values))

df['FROM_ID'] = df['FROM_ID'].replace(replace_dict)
```

Answering to the question in the comment, assume you create a csv with two columns: "To_Replace" and "Replace_Value"

```
     To_Replace    Replace_Value
0          X             Y
1          W             Z
2          A             B
```

You can create the replace_dict used in the script above like this:

```
import pandas as pd

replace_file = pd.read_csv(r'C:\Users\flabriol\Desktop\example_so.csv')
replace_dict = dict(zip(replace_file['To_Replace'], replace_file['Replace_Value']))
```

Comment: Any reason for down-voting?

Comment: hey, i have a question about the second part... how could i make a file and do a lookup or make an array that matches up the existing FROM_ID to a new value?

PS. I didn't downvote, I found it helpful, so i will upvote :)

Comment: I am not sure I fully understand your problem. Do you want to define the values you want to replace and the replacement values in a csv file?

Comment: Exacty. I would (ideally) love to have a list of values like this: var1:value1, varN:valueN, etc... then the program would look it up find varN and replace with valueN... hopefully that makes sense :)

Answer (score 1):

You're pretty close. All you need is:

```
print parts[2] + "/" + parts[0] + "/" + parts[1]
```

Comment: thanks! I was so close to this part... I was trying to join strings like this: print parts[1] . "/" parts[2] (ha, oh well, lesson learned!)

Answer (score 1):

```
import csv
f = open('reg.csv')
csv_f = csv.reader(f)

for row in csv_f:
    if "JOIN_DATE" in row: continue
    parts = row[1].split('/')
    data = "{}/{}/{}".format(parts[2],parts[1],parts[0])
print data
```

Comment: very cool, and since "print data" is the onscreen output i could write this to a new file, right? or pipe it into a new file? any recommendation?

Comment: If you want, you can write that data into a file using f.write(data).

Answer (score 1):

As to your second point, you should probably have a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/), which is a Python library for data analysis, especially of tabular data sets.

You could read in your data using

```
df = pd.read_csv("path_to_your_file")
```

which would return a `DataFrame` on which you can do operations such as selecting subsets, your example would become

```
df[df.FROM_ID == X]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
import datetime
.
.
datetime.datetime.strptime(row[1],'%d/%m/%Y').strftime('%Y/%m/%d')
```